# Show the function for which the Dirichlet generating series is $\zeta(2s)$ using only $\tau,\varphi,\sigma\text{ and }\mu$ or some explicit formula.

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, arithmetic-functions, dirichlet-series

I'm trying to find the function with Dirichlet generating series $\zeta(2s)$, I know that this relates somehow to the Liouville function but I am trying to express it in terms of only the standard arithmetic functions $\varphi,\tau,\sigma,\mu$ or some explicit formula. What I have tried so far is I know,

$$F_f(s)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{f(j)}{j^s}$$
$$F_f(s-1)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{jf(j)}{j^s}$$

And I have tried to find the g such that

$$F_g(s)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{g(j)}{j^{2s}}$$

But everything I have tried from this point onwards has been unsuccessful. Any help would be great.

Comment: $\zeta (2 s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{2 s}}$. If you want to write this in the form $\zeta (2 s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a(n)}{n^s}$, then $a(n)$ is $1$ when $n$ is an integer square and zero otherwise.

Comment: @StevenClark thank you for such a clear answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this sort of question, it is often a good idea to consider the effect on the Euler product:
$$ \zeta(2s) = \prod_p \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p^{2s}} \right)^{-1}. $$
This particular question happens to be relatively straightforward, as this is obviously multiplicative and this expression indicates that the coefficients are defined on prime powers by the function
$$ a(p^k) = \begin{cases} 1 & 2 \mid k \\ 0 & \text{else}. \end{cases} $$
This is, of course, another name for the "is a square" function.

Visually inspecting, we can quickly convince ourselves of this as well:
$$ \zeta(2s) = 1 + \frac{1}{4^s} + \frac{1}{9^s} + \frac{1}{16^s} + \frac{1}{25^s} + \cdots$$

Comment: $\zeta (2 s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{2 s}}\ne1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{p_n^{\ 2 s}}$ where $p_n$ is the $n^{th}$ prime.

Comment: Oh, hahaha. Let me rewrite my last example.